How can I pass the onClick event of a Floating Action Button that is in a Scaffold to another screen using Jetpack Compose?
I'm writing an app following the examples from Now In Android.
In Scaffold I have a Floating Action Button and I want to pass the onClick event of it to another screen, so I can take content from that screen and pass it to a text-to-speech (TTS) reader that will be displayed in a ModalBottomSheet.
My problem is that I don't know how to pass that event to capture it on the other screen.
This is the code where I load the Scaffold:
@Composable
fun LPlusApp(appState: LPlusAppState, onReaderClick: () -> Unit) {
    LPlusBackground {
        LPlusGradientBackground(/* code */) {
            val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
            val isOffline by appState.isOffline.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            val notConnectedMessage = stringResource(R.string.not_connected)
            
            LaunchedEffect(isOffline) {
                //...
            }
            
            // ...
            
            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.semantics {
                    testTagsAsResourceId = true
                },
                containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
                snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
                floatingActionButton =
                {
                    SmallFloatingActionButton(onClick = onReaderClick)
                        { Icon(Icons.Filled.PlayArrow, contentDescription = "") }

                },

                ) { padding ->
                
                // ...              
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is the code of MainActivity where I set the content:
setContent {
    val darkTheme = shouldUseDarkTheme(uiState)

    DisposableEffect(darkTheme) {
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(
                android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT,
                android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT,
            ) { darkTheme },
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(
                lightScrim,
                darkScrim,
            ) { darkTheme },
        )
        onDispose {}
    }

    val appState = rememberLPlusAppState(
        windowSizeClass = calculateWindowSizeClass(this),
        networkMonitor = networkMonitor,
        universalisRepository = universalisRepository,
        timeZoneMonitor = timeZoneMonitor,
    )

    val currentTimeZone by appState.currentTimeZone.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalAnalyticsHelper provides analyticsHelper,
        LocalTimeZone provides currentTimeZone,
    ) {
        LPlusTheme(
            darkTheme = darkTheme,
            androidTheme = shouldUseAndroidTheme(uiState),
            disableDynamicTheming = shouldDisableDynamicTheming(uiState),
        ) {
            @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3AdaptiveApi::class)
            LPlusApp(appState,{})
        }
    }
}

And this is the route and the screen where I want to catch the onReaderClick event:
@ExperimentalMaterial3AdaptiveApi
@Composable
fun UniversalisRoute(
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: UniversalisViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    onReaderClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    UniversalisScreen(
        uiState = uiState,
        modifier = modifier,
        onReaderClick = {
            Timber.d("Launch ModalBottomSheet with TTS")
        },
        onBackClick = onBackClick,
    )
}

The code is not working for me, how should I capture the onClick event of the Floating Action Button in UniversalisScreen?

Use Compose Navigation and pass an argument then launch your side effect.

Wouldn't the easiest way be to use Intents and Intents recivers? Like:
context.registerReceiver(
        reciverFunction,
        IntentFilter("YourActivity.INTENT_NAME"),
        RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    )

And:
intent=Intent("YourActivity.INTENT_NAME")
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", "DATA")
sendBroadcast(intent)

Hope this helps!
And I made no mistakes. This is how I would've done it

I have one Activity only. I want to catch the onClick event in another Screen (Jetpack Compose), not in another Activity.

What do you mean with "another screen", a different device?

No, another screen into the same application. See Navigation with Compose.

But you can still use Intents, why wouldn't you?
I changed it to sendBroadcast (sorry for that), but thats how i send data between different parts of my app
